# EPPLUS adding comment results error opening excel file

Tags: excel, load, epplus, xml-comments

I would like to add comments at one cell, So.. I did:

```cs
... 
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new MemoryStream());
var ws = package.WorkBook.WorkSheet[1];
ws.Cells[1, 1].AddComment("Lot Price: $12,000", "");
... 
package.SaveAs(new FileInfo("fileout.xlsx"));
package.Dispose();
```

When try open the resulted "fileout.xlsx", it showed a dialog box saying to recover as much as possible... Then the recovered fileout.xlsx displays errors:

"Removed Part: /xl/comments1.xml part with XML error.  (Comments) Load error. Line 5, column 0.
Removed Part: /xl/comments5.xml part with XML error.  (Comments) Load error. Line 5, column 24."

It appears that EPPlus produced a wrong format xml when there are comments.
I would like to share my solutions for this problem:

I just added a NON-BLANK header line for the comments, such as "REF" here:

```cs
ws.Cells[1, 1].AddComment("Lot Price: $12,000", "REF");
```

I hope someone might be helped by this.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me too. You should post your solution as an answer and accept that, if you can.

Answer (score 7):

Some one suggested to post it as answer. Here it is:

The problem disappears if like this:
I just added a NON-BLANK header line for the comments, such as "REF" here:

ws.Cells[1, 1].AddComment("Lot Price: $12,000", "REF");

I hope someone might be helped by this.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same problem.for my instance,I use function AddComent with empty value in second parameter.
at first ,my code like this:

```
ExcelRange range = newsheet.SelectedRange[1, 1];
newExcel.SetBGColor(range, Color.Red);
range.AddComment("no data", "");
```

then I change the last code like this:

```
range.AddComment("no data", "some body");
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

You can add a space " " it works too.